# Sending a Post request in postman pre-script

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

I am trying to send POST request in a pre-script using postman but getting error "There was an error in evaluating the Pre-request Script:  Error: Unexpected token '<' at 1:1  ^". Not sure whats wrong.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
pm.sendRequest({
url: 'http://localhost:8001/routes/d6b7a95a-fd91-4f8a-b8f6-10835f30170a',
method: 'PATCH',
headers: {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
body: { 
    mode: 'raw',
    raw:JSON.stringify({
        "protocols":["http","https"],
        "paths":["/target-paymentoriginal"],
        "methods":[]})}  }, 

function (err, response) {  console.log("Updated original route to target-payment"+response.json());  });
```

Comment: How you tried `header: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` - remove the `s` from your code.

Comment: @DannyDainton Thanks for pointing that out. Its working now. Save my day.

Comment: Added the answer so you can accept and close out the question. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The key for specifying the `headers` is incorrect.

It should be:

`header: {"Content-Type": "application/json"}` -

You need to remove the `s` from your code.